# Show me my vote and question counts at the top of the page

Tags: feature-request, voting, area-51

Would it be possible to show the number of Off Topic Votes, On Topic Votes and questions at the top of a proposal's page (and preferably in the proposal list as well)? Currently, the only way I can find to find the number of votes I have made is to either count the votes individually or try voting for both.